# How can I compare protein sequences to find closest match

Tags: alignment, sequence, bioinformatics, identity, protein-database

How could I build a tool to help with this scenario :

I work in a lab where we use plasmids to express recombinant proteins. We have a database containing all the plasmid identifiers and the sequence of the protein that they code for.

When a new protein is requested, I would like to be able to input the new desired protein sequence and search in our database for the plasmid that has the closest match to that sequence, with the highest identity score. The objective is to then use that existing plasmid and use it as a cloning template for the new plasmid.

In other words, I want to build a tool similar to NCBI blast that would work locally with proprietary sequences that are in an SQL database.

Would Python be able to achieve that ?

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome Marie to StackOverflow. You might have better luck posting your question to https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

However, is your database too large to perform an alignment of the new protein against all? Would it be possible to submit a name with the new protein to find a known homolog?

Comment: I think the database might be too large (more than a thousand sequences) but we can’t use only the names because several sequences code for the same protein, but with different punctual amino acid substitutions. 
Thanks for the advice I will try posting to that other site !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating your own local BLAST database with [`makeblastdb`](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK569841/)? Then you can use something like this:

```py
from Bio.Blast.Applications import NcbiblastnCommandline

run_command = NcbiblastnCommandline(query=YOUR_SEQUENCE_FASTA_PATH,
                                    db=DATABASE_PATH,
                                    out=RESULT_PATH,
                                    outfmt=5,
                                    [… other parameters …],
                                    evalue=1e-10
                                   )
```

```py
stdout, stderr = run_command()
```

Comment: That’s a very interesting option, I did not know that it was possible to use our own database with Blast. I will look into this, thanks !

Comment: @Marie-EveBouthot You are welcome! It is absolutely possible. I used it for our viruses database. Moreover, you can also use `Bio` package for reading & processing results.